# Сортировка HashMap в Java с помощью Stream API

Tags: java, сортировка, java-hashmap, java-stream

Приветствую. Помогите с такой вот задачей. Нужно отсортировать с помощью `Stream API HashMap`. Сначала сортировка происходит по значениям, а если значения равны, то по ключам. `Мапу` я получаю считав текст из консоли. Ключом является слово, а значением, кол-во раз сколько слово встретилось в тексте.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

    Map<String, Long> map = reader.lines().map(line -> line.split("[^\\p{L}\\p{Digit}]+"))
        .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
        .map(String::toLowerCase)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));

    map.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(
                (Function<Map.Entry<String, Long>, Long>) 

    Map.Entry::getValue).reversed())

        .limit(10)
        .sorted((e1, e2) -> {
            int comp = e2.getValue().compareTo(e1.getValue());
            if (comp == 0) {
                return e2.getKey().compareTo(e1.getKey());
            }
            return comp;
        })
        .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: А вопрос в чём?

Comment: как реализовать сортировку сначала по значениям, а если значения равны, то по ключам с помощью Stream API. Сейчас только по клчам сортируется

Answer (score 2):

Решил вот таким образом

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

    Map<String, Long> map = reader.lines().map(line -> line.split("[^\\p{L}\\p{Digit}]+"))
            .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
            .map(String::toLowerCase)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));


    map.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getKey))
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(
                    (Function<Map.Entry<String, Long>, Long>) Map.Entry::getValue).reversed())
            .limit(10)
            .forEach(x -> System.out.println(x.getKey()));
}
```